# Count doesn't work properly with UNION

Tags: php, mysql, count, union

Even after reading all related topic, nothing helps:

```
$q="select count(*) from (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
          FROM clips
         WHERE ((dimensions like('%concert%') AND dimensions NOT like('concert'))
            OR (file_format like('%concert%') AND file_format NOT like('concert')))
         UNION DISTINCT 
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
          FROM clips
         WHERE (dimensions like('concert') OR file_format like('concert'))
    ) AS num";
$q2 = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
$q3 = mysql_fetch_array($q2);
echo $q3['num'];
```

The error I get:

> Notice: Undefined index: num in .... on line ..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: whats in $q3 :) done a var_dump on it?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["count(*)"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Your `AS num` is in the wrong spot.

Comment: There's yer answer... the 2 elements in there are:$q3[0] and $q3['count(*)'] ...

Comment: and yeh... Rocket is correct ... that should be count(*) as num ...

Comment: Seems like a lot of fixes for the syntax are provided, but very few mentions that this query is only going to return a single row with either a 1 or 2.  The problem with this SQL appears to be bigger than the placement of the `as num` alias.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `num` to the table alias, not the count. Try this instead

```
$q="select count(*) AS num from (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM clips
     WHERE ((dimensions like('%concert%') AND dimensions NOT like('concert'))
        OR (file_format like('%concert%') AND file_format NOT like('concert')))
     UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM clips
     WHERE (dimensions like('concert') OR file_format like('concert'))
) AS sub_query_alias_that_is_required_but_pointless";
$q2 = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
$q3 = mysql_fetch_array($q2);
echo $q3['num'];
```

However, the more intended functionality you are probably looking for is to count the total rows, not count the counts like you have it. Furthermore, since you are just querying the `clips` table, I don't think you need a UNION at all. Based on the logic you have in the question, I think (but can't test it without your actual data) that it is logically equivalent to this very simple query, unless I am seriously missing something. This query might be friendlier and cleaner.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS num
FROM clips
WHERE dimensions like '%concert%' 
   OR file_format like '%concert%'
```

Comment: It dies with: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @Mark ok then give it a different alias, just not num. The point I was making was that you were calling the sub-query `num`, not the count result. I will edit to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Your query counts the results from a subquery called 'num'.

This means that there is no result called num, you could do something like `select count(*) as myNum from...` for that

Now what you are counting is:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
 FROM clips
 WHERE ((dimensions like('%concert%') 
         AND dimensions NOT like('concert')) 
       OR (file_format like('%concert%') AND file_format NOT like('concert'))) 
 UNION DISTINCT 
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM clips 
  WHERE (dimensions like('concert') OR file_format like('concert'))) AS num";
```

This will give you a counts, not results. So you are counting the counts, not adding them together.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. The 'selected' answer fixes the syntax problem, but doesn't appear to fix a more fundamental problem with the SQL.

Comment: instead of "count" might want to "sum" the 2 seperate results?

Answer (score 1):

Once you reformat your query, you'll see that the last "as num" is referred to the whole select, not to the count(*), which i guess it's what you want to alias.

Try to always format your queries in separate row for each entries, it greatly help your debugging.

Comment: Thanks, I will from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

I edited your question to better lay out the query. The issue is that you are assigning the alias to the subselect and not to the resulting value.  In addition, when you're counting the number of rows, for performance reasons, it's much better to do `count(1)` then `count(*)`, because `count(1) simply uses the constant in counting, while`count(*)` has to retrieve the actual rows before incrementing the count.  Try this instead:

```
$q="select count(1) as num from (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS total
          FROM clips
         WHERE ((dimensions like('%concert%') AND dimensions NOT like('concert'))
            OR (file_format like('%concert%') AND file_format NOT like('concert')))
         UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS total
          FROM clips
         WHERE (dimensions like('concert') OR file_format like('concert'))
    ) AS sub";
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! What is the meaning of "AS sub"? (since it made the change)

Comment: It didn't really make the difference.  The change in the first line "select count(1) as num" did it.  You may even be able to remove the last `AS sub".

Comment: Actually I can't. It dies with: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: This query returns a single row, with a value of either 1 or 2. The problem with the query appears to be bigger than the inclusion of an alias for the count(1) expression.

Comment: Well, frankly, the way the query is structured it would always return either 1 or 2.  Maybe, describe better what you're trying to achieve - then we'll be able to modify the query accordingly

Comment: I'm trying to find how many times "concert" (-for example) appears in the table. This query is based on another query that shows the results in reverse relevance order. I'm trying to avoid assembling one more query. If it is not possible this way I'll just keep the old way.

Answer (score 0):

Your query (once you alias the outermost `count(*) as num`, is going to return either 1 or 2, depending on whether the expressions aliased as "total" from your two subqueries are equal or not.

It's not necessary to use a UNION and to scan through the `clips` table twice to return this result.
A single scan will suffice. This query will return an equivalent result, with a single scan through the clips table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c.total_1 = c.total_2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS num
  FROM
(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ((dimensions like('%concert%') AND dimensions NOT like('concert'))
                  OR (file_format like('%concert%') AND file_format NOT like('concert')))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) AS total_1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN (dimensions like('concert') OR file_format like('concert'))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) AS total_2
  FROM clips
) c
```

That will likely run more efficiently than your query.

With all that said, it's not at all clear that this is the result set that you are really after.

---

ADDENDUM: Correction. This query is not entirely equivalent. This query will return a different result when the clips table is empty (contains no rows). That could be fixed, but I don't believe this is really the result set Mark is after.

To handle the condition where the clips table is empty:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IFNULL(c.total_1,0) = IFNULL(c.total_2,0) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS num
  FROM (SELECT 1) i LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ((dimensions like('%concert%') AND dimensions NOT like('concert'))
                  OR (file_format like('%concert%') AND file_format NOT like('concert')))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) AS total_1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN (dimensions like('concert') OR file_format like('concert'))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) AS total_2
  FROM clips
) c
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax (because of my limited knowledge in MySQL), so I just copy-pasted it and the result is: "Every derived table must have its own alias". Was the code cut (the last char is "c")?

Comment: The last character in those SQL statements, ("c") is the required alias for the derived table. It needs to be there.